# How do I communicate between two modules in GWT

Tags: gwt

Hi I am currently facing communicating with two GWT modules.
1. enquiry.html
2. info.html

In enquiry.html i have search results on click of a hyperlink I need to open the info module. Its working fine in my development environment, but when I deploy in linux its causing issue.

Basically when the info.html is loading up, its not able to identify the info.nocache.js

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can put parameters on the URL, like `info.html?resultId=432001`

Then, in your code, you can access resultId with

```
String resultId = com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getParameter("resultId");
```

Comment: Thanks Riley. That helped. Appreciate your response.